# How to return 404 if path starts with '/api' and there is a file mapped as fallback?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have an asp.net core 6.0 app with:

- `WeatherForecastController`
- `index.html`  in `wwwroot` folder.

I have configured `index.html`as file fallback. This is the`main` method of `program.cs`;

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapControllers();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
    app.Run();
}
```

I wanted to return 404 when the `path` starts with `/api` and there is no matching controller action.

I tried adding a middleware after `app.MapControllers`but the middleware executes before the controller gets called and the app always returns 404 when trying to call the API.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.MapControllers();
    app.UseApiNotFound();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
    app.Run();
}
```

This is the middleware:

```
public class ApiNotFoundMiddleware
{

    private readonly RequestDelegate next;
    public ApiNotFoundMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    private static PathString prefix = "/api";

    public Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(prefix))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

So

How to return 404 if path starts with '/api', there is no matching controller action and there is a file mapped as fallback?

or

is there a way to restrict fallback file to paths that do not start with `/api`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a different IApplicationBuilder for different conditions in your Progam.cs or Startup.cs:

e.g.:

```
app.MapWhen(ctx => !ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), appBuilder =>
{
    appBuilder.UseRouting();
    appBuilder.UseEndpoints(ep =>
    {
        ep.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
    });
});
```

Comment: You need to call to `appBuilder.UseRouting()` before `UseEndpoints`, if you don't do it index.html is shown even for non api paths. Please, could you replace DoNotApiSuff with UseRouting, so I can mark this as the accepted answer?

Comment: Fair enough.  Yes, my intention was just to show the UseEndpoints options available to you and custom appBuilder calls.  But, agree, answer will be clearer as you've suggested.  Edit incoming.

Answer (score 0):

if you add `app.UseMiddleware<ApiNotFoundMiddleware>();` here like so :

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseMiddleware<ApiNotFoundMiddleware>();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

This returns 404 if you try navigate to anything with /api

Would this be what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: No. I wanted to return 404 if there is no matching controller action, but it returns 404 always.