# ASP.Net Core MVC project with added Web API controller vs. ASP.Net Core Web API project

Tags: asp.net-core

I would like to have a clear idea whether ASP.Net Core MVC project with added Web API controllers has any disadvantage when compared to ASP.Net Core Web API project to develop
web api functionality. Because an ASP.Net Core MVC project with added Web API controllers can have ready to use options like identity, roles, db tables read/write etc. Thanks for any answers, comments.

Answer (score 1):

There are no issues with your approach.

The different project templates in Visual Studio will create appropriate registrations in your program.cs or startup.cs file for the baseline template you select.

These registrations can then be edited by you to enhance the solution as required, e.g. adding support for Api in an MVC project as asked in your question.

Here's a link that will clarify what the different registration options do:

https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/difference-between-addmvc-and-addmvccore-method/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Neil. I doubt how to write Startup.cs --> services CORS for only api controller in an ASP.Net core mvc project which also has api controller for example.

Comment: To conditionally set up the application pipeline based on route, see my linked answer to another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72460486/how-to-return-404-if-path-starts-with-api-and-there-is-a-file-mapped-as-fallb/72460809#72460809

Comment: You can then choose whether to AddCors based on the request route.